# How to use pcap_open_live for a particular ethernet port

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, winpcap

For the function below, if I want to obtain a packet capture handle on a particular ethernet port out of many, where can I get the value for 
argument **const char *device** ?

```
pcap_t *pcap_open_live(const char *device, int snaplen, int promisc, int to_ms, char *errbuf);
```

Answer (score 1):

Devices are of the [format](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__remote__source__string.html) `rpcap://device`, where every port has a different device string. The [WinPcap tutorial](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut.html)'s very first page shows how to use [`pcap_findalldevs_ex`](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcapfunc.html#ga98f36e62c95c6ad81eaa8b2bbeb8f16e) to enumerate all devices: [Obtaining the device list](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut1.html).

The [first complete example](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut3.html) shows how to use it in conjunction with `pcap_open`. I would advise you to follow the tutorial. It's quite good.